# Visual Studio's bug: editor tabs (code tabs) appear->hide->appear forever => non-responsive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I love to open many tabs (10-30) of `.cpp` and `.h`, so the tab are *overflowed* to the right, i.e. Visual Studio can't show named of all opened tabs at the same time.  (which is ok)

[image]

When I pin a new tab or change Visual Studio resolution (resize its window), Visual Studio will try to determine which one should be shown and which one should not (that is what I think).

In rare cases (1%), Visual Studio fail to do so.   After I pin a new code tab (e.g. `.cpp`), it loops forever.  For example, in the image, it is possible that the last of the four tabs will appear -> hide -> appear -> ... so on  (forever).

Visual Studio would try to update other GUI to match the appearance/disappearance of the tab (e.g. width of console pane ?).

Within about 1-3 seconds, if I don't resize the window, Visual Studio will become unresponsive.
I will have to terminate it, lose some of my work.

It is like a mini-game.

I am sure that is a bug of Visual Studio.  Have anyone faced it?
(Please comment if you faced the same problem!)

I don't think it is related to plugin "Visual Assist" or "Resharper".
I always set my monitor to low-resolution (1280 x 720), but I don't think it is a problem.

**Question:** How to solve this *swappy* bug, or at least avoid/alleviate it?

Comment: Try to disable the plugins, try to run on a higher resolution.

Comment: @Raw N   That is quite hard to verify, the bug occurs on rare cases.  Furthermore, I don't think they are the causes, I don't have much incentive to disable them / change resolution (do those things can reduce my productivity).  I know it sound stubborn, but those information are only provided just in case.  :)

Comment: Have you posted this to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio already? That's the place for VS bug reports, not so much SO. Anyway I agree with Raw N: *thinking* a plugin isn't the problem doesn't buy you much. Disable all plugins, even MS-signed ones, then check if the bug is still there (people at MS Connect will ask you the same)